# Invalid Form Key, Please Refresh Page at Checkout Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key, memcached

i havent changed any cookies settings that some people have mentioned to try. I did install memcache, im not sure if that is related.

local.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Fri, 17 May 2013 03:32:24 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[RANDOMNUMBER]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[DATABASE]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
  <!-- START new connection to wordpress database !-->
            <wordpress_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[USERNAME]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[PASSWORD]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[DATABASE]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                    <use>0</use>
                </connection>
            </wordpress_setup>
            <!-- FINISH new connection to wordpress database !-->
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
<cache>
               <backend>ewfile</backend>
           <slow_backend>ewfile</slow_backend>
          </cache>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[ADMIN]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Memcached in theory shouldn't be used on your checkout. It potentially could cache user data and show it to someone else.

It sounds like your form key might be getting cached into memcached by another user and then when you visit/a separate customer visits the checkout they have the cached form key rather than their own.

It might be worth disabling memcached and then retrying the checkout, if it works then there is most likely something wrong in the configuration for memcached.

Some useful information regarding memcached configuration for magento: https://redislabs.com/lp/magento-memcached/

Comment: is there a way to create an exception within memcache so checkout is not cached?

Comment: @DanCarylon im using it as shown in the link you provided

Comment: Are you serving the checkout over https as this _should_ not get cached and means there are other problems.

Comment: @Jackel2017 can you post your cache xml settings

Comment: yes, i use HTTPS at checkout.  where is this setting? cache xml?

Comment: i just used firebug during checkout. and i noticed one form key being used then i clicked checkout, it gives me the invalid form key. I then refresh and click checkout again and its successful and i noticed it issued a new form key. From my understanding, this error only happens with customers or already have an account and login. After refreshing it works everytime but why does it happen to begin with is the issue.

Comment: The cache settings should be in your local.xml or possibly in a cache.xml in your `app/etc/` To enable magento to use memcached properly you should have set some values there

Comment: can you make this a chat?

Comment: SEE FILE HERE : http://textuploader.com/dtsoo

Comment: There's nothing in there that tells Magento to use Memcached.

Comment: i use a extension called extendware (thats the call out ewfile) and on the backend we choose memcache. http://www.extendware.com/magento-full-page-cache.html

Comment: I'd suggest getting hold of the developer of that extension, if you've bought it through their website i should imagine you would have some sort of support with it.

Comment: The thing is, how do i know that is what is creating the problem?

Comment: By debugging. You mentioned you recently installed memcached. My first port of call would be to remove/disable that and see if the problem is resolved. Based on your other comment about firebug it sounds to me like you have cached form_keys. As the form key in the html is cached and then the page is served from the cache.

Comment: so do agree with me, you think its a cache issue?

Comment: From everything you've said, I would have to agree it does appear to be a cache issue

Comment: i disabled the cache and so far it seems like it works. Something related to the cache for sure. Thank you.

Comment: Wish i could help more with it but i don't know anything about that extension. Technically you shouldn't need any extensions to use memcached. Maybe that extension is trying to cache _to much_ and is caching the checkout or just not hole punching correctly.